# loop through values and update after each one completes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cursor

I have the following code that i need to run for 350 locations it takes an hour to do 5 locations so I run 5 at a time by using where location_code in ('0001', '0002', '0003', '0005', '0006') I would like to create a temp table with 2 columns one location_id and the other completed and loop through each value on the location_id column then update the completed column with date and time stamp when complete and commit after each. This way I can just let it run and if i need to kill it i can see the last completed location_id and know where to restart the process from or better yet have it check for a vaule in the completed column and if exists go to the next .....

```
--Collecting all records containing remnant cost. You will need to specify the location     number(s). In the example below we're using location 0035
select sku_id, ib.location_id, price_status_id, inventory_status_id, sum(transaction_units) as units, sum(transaction_cost) as cost, 
sum(transaction_valuation_retail) as val_retail, sum(transaction_selling_retail) as sell_retail
into #remnant_cost 
from ib_inventory ib
inner join location l on l.location_id = ib.location_id
where location_code in ('0001', '0002', '0003', '0005', '0006')
group by sku_id, ib.location_id, price_status_id, inventory_status_id
having sum(transaction_units) = 0
and sum(transaction_cost) <> 0


--Verify the total remnant cost.
select location_id, sum(units) as units, sum(cost) as cost, sum(val_retail) as val_retail, sum(sell_retail) as sell_retail
from #remnant_cost
group by location_id

select *
from #remnant_cost

----------------------------------------------------Run above this line first and gather results--------------------------------


--inserting into a temp table the cost negation using transaction_type_code 500 (Actual shrink) before inserting into ib_inventory
--corrected query adding transaction date as column heading (Marshall)
select
sku_id, location_id, price_status_id, convert(smalldatetime,convert(varchar(50),getdate(),101)) as transaction_date, 500 as transaction_type_code, inventory_status_id, NULL as other_location_id, 
NULL as transaction_reason_id, 999999 as document_number, 0 as transaction_units, cost * -1 as transaction_cost, 0 as transaction_valuation_retail, 
0 as transaction_selling_retail,NULL as price_change_type, NULL as units_affected
into #rem_fix
from #remnant_cost


--Validating to make sure cost will have the exact opposite to negate.
select location_id, sum(transaction_units) as units, sum(transaction_cost) as cost, sum(transaction_valuation_retail) as val_retail, 
sum(transaction_selling_retail) as sell_retail
from #rem_fix
group by location_id


BEGIN TRAN

EXEC inventory_update_$sp 'SELECT      sku_id,location_id,price_status_id,transaction_date,transaction_type_code,inventory_status_id,other_location_id,
transaction_reason_id,document_number,transaction_units,transaction_cost,transaction_valuation_retail,transaction_selling_retail,price_change_type,
units_affected FROM #rem_fix'

COMMIT
```

Comment: Have you looked at an [execution plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx) to see if there are any performance issues that might be easily addressed? Tip: It is generally helpful with DB questions to include a tag for the version of the software, e.g. `sql-server-2014`, since they have different features available.

Comment: The sql has been tuned and is running efficient its just the amount of data i need to go through, this is on SQL 2005

Comment: How are you going to update the table?  You have some specific dynamic SQL stored procedure that you'll need to give us the definition to (`inventory_update_$sp`).

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about your schema:

```
-- A working table to track progress that will stick around.
create table dbo.Location_Codes
  ( Location_Code VarChar(4), Started DateTime NULL, Completed DateTime NULL );
```

Then break up the work this way:

```
if not exists ( select 42 from dbo.Location_Codes where Completed is NULL )
  begin
  -- All of the locations have been processed (or this is the first time through).
  delete from dbo.Location_Codes;
  -- Get all of the location codes.
  insert into dbo.Location_Codes
    select Location_Code, NULL, NULL
      from Location;
  end

-- Temporary table to make things easier.
declare @Pass_Location_Codes as Table ( Location_Code VarChar(4) );

-- Loop until all locations have been processed.
while exists ( select 42 from dbo.Location_Codes where Completed is NULL )
  begin
  -- Get the next five locations for which processing has not completed.
  delete from @Pass_Location_Codes;
  insert into @Pass_Location_Codes
    select top 5 Location_Code
      from dbo.Location_Codes
      where Completed is NULL
      order by Location_Code;
  -- Record the start date/time.
  update dbo.Location_Codes
    set Started = GetDate()
    where Location_Code in ( select Location_Code from @Pass_Location_Codes );

  -- Run the big query.
  select ...
    where Location_Code in ( select Location_Code from @Pass_Location_Codes )
    ...

  -- Record the completion date/time.
  update dbo.Location_Codes
    set Completed = GetDate()
    where Location_Code in ( select Location_Code from @Pass_Location_Codes );
  end
```